# How to Set Mac OS X LDAP to Use Remote Home Folder

Tags: mac, nfs, osx-el-capitan, openldap

I have a MacOSX El Capitan machine that uses LDAP for authentication.
This part already works and I can log onto the machine with LDAP accounts.

I set the NFSHomeDirectory as #/Users/$uid$ which creates local directories for the accounts.

I want to be able to mount our own home directories that already exist on a different server.
The LDAP already has objects for auto_home and auto_osx for each user.

```
dn: automountKey=userid,automountmapname=auto_osx,dc=domain,dc=com
    automountKey: userid
    automountInformation: server:/path/to/userid/support/osx
    objectClass: automount
    objectClass: top
```

How do I get OSX to mount the remote home directory and use that to folder to create all of the Desktop, Documents, etc. on there and not locally?

I cannot change the LDAP server, but I can try to provide more information if needed. I am also not really familiar with how automount works at all.